# Getting DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505 from DB2

Tags: hibernate, db2, constraints

I am executing this sql from jpa-hibernate for a db2 database:

update SCO_IC_RELACIONES_PAISES set IC_ID=null where IC_ID=2 and ID=12

The error I am getting is:

```
2018-06-14 18:21:47,203 ERROR 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper ::: **DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=2;SCOPEDES.SCO_IC_RELACIONES_PAISES, DRIVER=4.24.92**

2018-06-14 18:21:47,203 ERROR 1 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl ::: HHH000346: **Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException**: could not execute statement]
```

The wierd thing is that if I execute the same sql from a db2 client(like oracle sql developer), the update is successful.

1. The error I am getting is from database or is from hibernate before sending the sql to database? If it is from database, why if I execute directly the sql on a db2 client, the sql is executed ok?

Attached image with table structure

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The -803 is a duplicate key value , and it comes from Db2.  A possible reason it is not happening from Oracle-SQL-Developer may be that the Oracle-SQL-Developer is accessing a different database or schema or table, or that the SQL which is throwing the exception is not what you think.